# Javascript 3D Frameworks running on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, frameworks, 3d

I need to develop a demo in 3D using html5 and javascript but this must run on mobile. I know a little about webgl but I think it needs graphic card support. 
I tested a few demos in my Samsung SII and it does not work.

Can anyone give me information about 3D javascript frameworks that have compatibility with smartphones?

Regards,

Comment: A Google search would be faster than waiting for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebGL is supported on some mobile web browsers,

I did a quick google search I found that these support WebGl

1. Nokia N900
2. BlackBerry PlayBook
3. Firefox for mobile
4. Sony Ericsson Xperia range of Android smartphones have had WebGL capabilities following a firmware upgrade
5. Opera Mobile 12
6. Tizen 1.0

This list may be out date as I found it on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL#Mobile_Browsers)

Another site that might give you some info is this [WebGL Compatibility page](http://caniuse.com/webgl)

***EDIT***

Another framework that allows to deploy JavaScript, HTML5 Apps and it works on mobile platforms is CocoonJS,
here is the [supported feature list](http://wiki.ludei.com/cocoonjs%3afeaturelist)

Comment: I see that CocoonJS is a framework that use openGL. Other people recommend Three.js or other frameworks that use openGL and not code openGL as it is (web gl of course). But there is other alternative thatn OPENGL?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, the whole thing uses html5 and javascript if that is what you need to know

Answer (score 1):

ThreeJS does canvas 2d , webgl and svg rendering so it depends on your mobile capabilities

http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/

you also have CSS 3D transforms so depending on what you need to do that can be an option.

Comment: because the demos may not use Canvas2D renderer  ,and may use some javascript stuffs not available on your modile, you have different way to render content in ThreeJS but you have to actually set up the right renderer yourself , does your phone support canvas or svg ?